# How to use same http request in AngularJS to Web Api?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, httprequest

I have following code running in loop for file upload. Each loop iteration creates new xhr. Is there any way to use same connection? I am using AngularJS, ng-file-upload and asp.net webapi. [image: xhr requets]

```
file.upload = Upload.upload({
url:api url,
method: 'POST',
data: { file: file, 'key1': value1, 'key2': value2},
FormData: metadata
});
```

Comment: You could upload them all in one request, but usually multiple small requests will be faster than one big one. Or use web sockets if you really want to have like a stream of uploads sharing a single connection. But unless you upload large amounts of files, I would just keep the seperate requests. So can you please explain better what the problem is with having multiple xhr requests?

Comment: @Shilly i am optimizing file uploads in application.As you said, "multiple small requests will be faster than one big one", for large files i am chunking file and sending it to servers. So there can be approx 50 chunks for large files to be uploaded at once. so to optimize further i had idea of using single connection.

Comment: Then I would suggest looking into web sockets to handle file chunks of files larger than like, one or two gigabytes. And just keep xhr for smaller files, since browsers have gotten rather good at handling the overhead of large fiile uploads.

Comment: @Shilly thanks a lot for help. I am looking into websockets, mean while if you can suggest some good resource for websockets using AngularJS and webapi, it would be great.

Comment: No idea about resources alas, since I haven't had the need yet to use them in asp. But there's bound to be an asp websocket toturial somewhere.